# Jenkins permission to build in home dir

Tags: permissions, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I am trying to build a Git project using Jenkins on an ec2 instance. The custom workspace address I want to keep is `/home/ec2-user/xyz`.

I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs:
```

I figured that this is due to permission, that 'jenkins' user doesn't have the permission to that folder.

So, I changed the ownership of `xyz`, and added jenkins as a user and a group, and tried to change the permission to 777.

Still the error persists.

I tried building this in other `/var/www/` and it builds correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that you gave permission to the `xyz` directory but did not give write permission to `/home` as well. You'd have to change the group of `/home` to `jenkins` and give it 775 permission.

However, the cleanest way would be to use the default values for Jenkins directories.

Comment: I had considered that option, but rejected it because /var(for which the build was successful) had the same permissions and owners as /home. Anyway I tried and it worked, although there was a problem with cleaning the directory

Comment: on a similar note if a parent directory does not have the required ownership or permission and child directory does have both. Does it work?

Comment: No, all traversed directories from `/` to destination need to have the correct ownership/permission.